# Data Link Layer

Tags: networking

I've been reading about TCP/IP layers and I've gotten a bit confused.

When we talk about the `Data Link Layer` it is said that it is responsible for end-to-end communication, but yet it states that the DLL receives datagram and encapsulates it into a frame and forwards it to the physical layer.

I would like to know which one it really is, whether the DLL sends the datagram to the destination datagram, or to the physical layer?

Answer (score 0):

The TCP/IP model specifies the responsiblities of various layers required to abstract away the technicality of tranporting network packets from one endpoint to another. The data link layer is responsible for sending packets between two endpoints which are directly connected by a medium (e.g. ethernet cable, optic fibre, radio waves) by identifying each endpoint by a unique address (MAC address). The physical layer has the responsibility of transporting the bits of data over the medium (e.g. translating a bit to light pulses in an optic fibre), this layer is handled by hardware. The datalink layer handles the sending to an endpoint, while the physical layer handles the passing of bits on the medium (the data link packet is 'translated' to the representation of data on the medium).